# Pandas: Remove rows per group based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's assume that I have the following data-frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], "date": [pd.Timestamp(2016, 7, 29), pd.Timestamp(2017, 8, 22), pd.Timestamp(2017, 10, 9), pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 9), pd.Timestamp(2018, 3, 31), pd.Timestamp(2018, 7, 5)], "other_col": [11.1, 77.7, 22.2, 33.3, 44.4, 88.8]})
```

What I want to achieve is delete the last `N` rows for each group where the `data-frame is grouped by id` such that `N` is: The number of rows that have a `date` that is within 3 months of the `date` of the last row (This will delete the last row). The resulting data-frame should be:

```
r_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 2], "date": [pd.Timestamp(2016, 7, 29), pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 9), pd.Timestamp(2018, 3, 31)], "other_col": [11.1, 33.3, 44.4]})
```

- The rows of the data-frame will always be ordered
- The last row should also be removed because by default its date is within the "delete" range of dates for each group.

Comment: You can use `df.groupby('id').apply(delete_last_three_months)` if you write the function `delete_last_three_months` that works on a single dataframe. As each group in `groupby` is just another dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single date-based lambda function can handle the problem. It doesn't even care about sorting the rows.

```
df.groupby('id').apply(
  lambda x: x.loc[
    x.date < (x.date.max() - pd.Timedelta(3, unit='M'))
  ]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Update**:

As @jpp pointed out, the following selection is much (~12x) faster:

```
df[df['date'] < (df.groupby('id')['date'].transform('max') - pd.Timedelta(3, unit='M'))]
```

As an added bonus, it also preserves the original order and indices.

Comment: Similar idea, probably more efficient: `df = df[df['date'] < (df.groupby('id')['date'].transform('max') - pd.Timedelta(3, unit='month'))]`. This avoids the Python-level loop in `apply` and also avoids having to call `reset_index`.

Comment: @jpp Cool! I never realized you could use the groupby function like this for indexing. I'll experiment with this a bit to see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_n_row(grouped_df):
  last_row_date = grouped_df.iloc[-1]['date']
  grouped_df_filtered = grouped_df[(grouped_df['date'] <=last_row_date) & (grouped_df['date'] <=last_row_date - timedelta(days=90))]
  return grouped_df_filtered

from datetime import timedelta
r_df = df.groupby('id').apply(remove_n_row).reset_index(drop=True)
print(r_df)
```

OUTPUT

```
    id     date     other_col
0   1   2016-07-29   11.1
1   2   2018-01-09   33.3
2   2   2018-03-31   44.4
```